# IIS page URL rewrite gives a HTTP Error 400 with parameter string longer than 260 characters long

Tags: iis, iis-10

My environment is as follows:

IIS version is 10.0.17763.1
Running on Windows Server 2019 datacenter

On remote server I have a rest server (as a windows service) running on port 8041 which accepts calls with http. I have created a IIS website that runs on port 9010 that re-writes the calls via a https domain that redirects to the service running on 8041 port and vise versa. I can access both services separately and they both work fine under following scenarios:

Service running on 8041 port:

http://:8041/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is longer than 260 characters>

http://:8041/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is less than 260 characters https://:9010/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is less than 260 characters long>

> 

website running on port 9010:

https://:9010/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is less than 260 characters long>

however following scenario does not work:

**https://:9010/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is longer than 260 characters https://:9010/rest/AccountModule/GetUserSettings/<parameter string that is less than 260 characters long>

> **

the call gives the following error:

````
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>```

I have tried many things such as configuration editor changes in IIS increase the limits maxRequestLength, maxUrlLength and maxQueryStringLength and adding new DWORD values to the registry files (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters). They are as follows and none of them seems to work. 

[IIS-Configuration-Editor-Changes][1]
[Registry_Changes_Http][2]


my web config file content is as follows:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8041/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" maxUrl="6000000" maxQueryString="6000000">
                    <headerLimits>
                    </headerLimits>
                </requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="httpRuntime" value="maxUrlLength" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxUrlLength="50000" maxQueryStringLength="50000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Help on fixing this long URL parameters (longer than 260 characters) is much appreciated.

Thanks
Dan


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q82p6.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIoRq.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After these configuration changes are completed, you need to restart the http service to take effect:

1. Run the command prompt in search bar
2. At the command prompt, type `net stop http`, then press `Enter`.
3. At the command prompt, type `net start http`, then press `Enter`.

I noticed that the values of some of your parameters are not set to the maximum, you can try the following configuration parameters:

1. Modify the httpRuntime node to add `maxQueryStringLength`, `maxRequestLength` configuration:

   ```
   <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2097151" maxRequestLength="2097151" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" executionTimeout="36000" delayNotificationTimeout="36000" />
   ```
2. Modify the `system.webServer` node:

   ```
   <security>
     <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" allowHighBitCharacters="true"  >
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097151" maxQueryString="2097151" maxUrl="2097151" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   ```

According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows) from Microsoft, you can modify the following two values in the registry:

[image]

The setting of `UrlSegmentMaxCount` is the same as above, the value is also Dword 2048.

Comment: Hi samwu, I have done all except for that "net stop http" and "net start http" commands as "net stop http" will stop while trying to stop HTTP Server service. and Then I cant restart or stop it again. However I re-started the server and that should run the "net stop http" and  "net start http" commands automatically,I believe.  But the problem still remains. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Are you using DWORD (32-bit) or QWORD (64-bit)?

Comment: DWORD.  I have attached a screenshot on the question. but it is not visible. please check it on this link. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIoRq.png).

Comment: I still think you need to restart the http service to take effect.

Comment: Hi Samwu, Your solution seems to working fine. My issues seems to be related with a virtual machine in Azure. Thanks for the detailed answer.